# Unable to turn on Wake on LAN (WoLAN / WoWLAN) using ethtool

Tags: networking, wlan, lan

```
sudo ethtool <devicename>
Settings for <devicename>:
    Link detected: yes
```

No details regarding `Supports Wake-on` show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`NetworkManager`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/nmcli.1.html) cli

First get the connection name

```
nmcli connection show
```

Then, check the existing **wake-on** setting

```
nmcli connection show "connection-name" | grep wake-on
802-11-wireless.wake-on-wlan:           0x0 ()
```

Then, modify the required setting as per your need

```
nmcli connection modify "connection-name" 802-11-wireless.wake-on-wlan 8
```

References

1. Search `NM_SETTING_WIRED_WAKE_ON_LAN_MAGIC` and `NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_WAKE_ON_WLAN_MAGIC` in [`man nm-settings-nmcli`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/nm-settings-nmcli.5.html).
2. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wake-on-LAN#NetworkManager